# Rails Datatypes,length and Datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For an alphanumeric input, what kind of datatype should i use in Rails?
Also how can i edit the length of the input, like Min 5 characters to Max 30 characters. ?
Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From very little i got your question i guess you want something like following

For an alphanumeric input, what kind of datatype should i use in Rails?

```
It should be varchar (string)
```

Also how can i edit the length of the input, like Min 5 characters to Max 30 characters. ? 
Ref [`this`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

```
validates :first_name, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 30 }
```